# Emacs-client - whats the minimal installation?

Tags: emacs, installation, client, updates

Lets say I have an Emacs-Server running on some remote server, with all the libraries and software necessary for running my application.

Then I want several clients to connect to that remote machine, using Emacs-client. Does each client need a full Emacs installation, or is there a minimal installation that is just enough to communicate with the remote server, where all the action is?

Could this (Emacs-)client installation be so minimal, that almost all software-updates can be done on the server, without affecting the Emacs-clients?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason not to run the clients remotely as well, and simply use a local display? That way, pretty much all you need on the local machines is the ssh client and the X Window server.

`ssh -X (user)@(server) "emacsclient -c"`

---

Edits for the comments:

This command starts a new client to connect to an existing Emacs server (which it assumes is already running). You can use `"emacsclient -a '' -c"` to automatically start `emacs --daemon` if there is no existing server, but I don't know whether you want the connecting user to be starting the server.

In fact, I'm pretty unsure about the whole multi-user side of this to be honest, as I've never done that before. Authentication for the above is handled by ssh, but there may well be subsequent permission issues to deal with, or similar, when the server and the clients are started by different users.

This approach should be *possible* with Windows/Cygwin as client and/or server, as Cygwin provides Emacs, OpenSSH, and X.org packages. (I regularly use Windows/Cygwin as a local display for Emacs running on Linux.) It may be harder to set up, though, and any permissions issues are probably different when you're using Cygwin.

I'm less sure how this would work without Cygwin. NTEmacs certainly won't talk to X.org, so I imagine you'd be terminal based in that instance. (There *are* probably other options, but Cygwin sounds to me like the best-integrated approach to using all of Emacs, SSH, and X on Windows).

Lastly, I imagine you're probably getting your "Connection refused" error because localhost is not running a sshd daemon? I would say that configuration of ssh is outside the scope of this question, but there are lots of resources online for that.

Comment: Great, thanks. Something simple like that, where all updating and all mantainance takes place on the server, and no installation is necessary, was exactly what I was looking for. I don't have a remote server to try it out at the moment, would that work on localhost too? Is that limited to linux-machines, or is it possible on windows too (with/without cygwin)?

Comment: Some more questions: does this start a new emacsclient, or connect to an existing one? It would be convenient, if Emacs runs all the time on the server and the emacs-clients are only started on demand from the client machines. How would authentication work in a setting like this?

Comment: When I try:  sudo ssh -X tj1@localhost "emacsclient -c"  I get  
ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused

Comment: I've updated the answer. Testing this out may actually entail much more effort than you were hoping for, as I had imagined that the rest of the infrastructure was already in place.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is what I was looking for so its no problem to investigate a little. I already found this about authentication: "SSH keys allow authentication between two hosts without the need of a password. SSH key authentication uses two keys a private key and a public key. 
ssh-keygen -t dsa
By default the public key is saved in the file ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub, while ~/.ssh/id_dsa is the private key. Now copy the id_dsa.pub file to the remote host and append it to ~/.ssh/authorized_keys by entering:
ssh-copy-id username@remotehost
double check the permissions on the authorized_keys file"

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you're trying to achieve, you may be able to use a combination of Emacs and Screen. By starting up Emacs from Screen on the remote machine and detaching from it, you can subsequently re-attach from a different machine that doesn't have Emacs. Again, whether this will work for you or not depends on what you're trying to do; however, for many Emacs use-cases, this can be very effective. If you're not familiar with using Screen in this manner, here is some reading material:

[screen - The Terminal Multiplexer](http://www.bangmoney.org/presentations/screen.html)

Comment: That is a completely new concept for me but quite interesting. I would like to use a very restricted version of Emacs-client like a replacement for the web-browser in a typical client-server application, suitable for non-experts without complicated installation routines. I'll have to look if screen is easy enough too use, but it sounds promising. Thanks.

Comment: If (after researching this a bit more) you decide that the combination of Emacs and Screen might do what you need, you might want to ask a new question that specifically details what you would like to achieve using Emacs and Screen. That way, you're more likely to get good responses.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that would be possible. emacsclient uses tramp to connect to a remote server, and just by looking at the number of `require`s in the tramp elisp files (41) it seems very unlikely. You can try it yourself with the following:

`zgrep -oE "\(require '[a-z-]+\)" *el.gz | sed -e 's%[a-z0-9-]\+\.el\.gz:%%g' | sort | uniq -cu | wc -l`

Comment: Thanks, that is not what I hoped for. Maybe, with Emacs 24 it will be easier to just install a minimum core version of Emacs (client) locally and have all the libraries on a remote server, accessible by all clients. By the way, amazing Linux command-line wizardry.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in emacsclient, but I don't think is was designed to do what you're looking for.  I think the general use case is that emacsclient allows you to redirect new requests to open a file with emacs to a persistent emacs process to avoid what may be a bit of an overhead in startup time.  You seem to be looking for more of a true client/server relationship.

I think to meet the goal you're aiming at you'll probably need to look a little outside emacs,  probably a project unto itself - 'emacsRemoteClient.  It boils down to one or two models; the file you want to edit would need to have it's path sent over to the server machine so that emacs could do some sort of remote tramp access & then spawn the xwindow locally (using the local X env or requiring an x server on windows)... or two, transferring the file to some temp location on the server box and again spawning the remote x window locally (followed by syncing the changes between the tmp & local file).

Would be cool to have something like that... but suspecting it'll involve a bit of work.  Maybe we just need a version of emacs written in javascript and it can live in the cloud or on your browser... oh to have emacs keybindings in the browser ;-)

-Steve

Comment: Hi Steve, sounds interesting, and I think zev and phils showed in their answers with how little outside Emacs this might work. By the was - do you know conkeror? Thats a web browser written in javascript modeled after Emacs, with buffers and Emacs keybindings.